# Commerce Paypal- How can I change the "Order No. at Site Name" string?

Tags: commerce

I'm using the Commerce PayPal module to redirect users to PayPal to pay for their orders.

However, when I do this, the transaction that Commerce provides to PayPal is called

> Order # at [Site name]

However, on my site, the store is just one part of it, and the store has a different name than the rest of the site, so I would like to override this string and replace `[Site name]` with the explicit name of my store.

However, I haven't been able to track down where I can edit this.  I tried searching for a number of variations on the *Translate interface* page and I also tried using `grep` on my modules directory but I haven't been able to locate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of my payment gateway modules, and my recommended best practice for others', is to include a final opportunity before the payment API request is dispatched for developers to alter the request parameters if desired. How you do that in the PayPal modules depends on which payment method you're using. I'm going to assume this is a PayPal Payments Standard (WPS) initiated payment, so the hook you want is:

[hook_commerce_paypal_wps_order_form_data_alter()](http://drupalcode.org/project/commerce_paypal.git/blob/refs/heads/7.x-2.x:/modules/wps/commerce_paypal_wps.api.php)

If it's one of the others, refer to their *.api.php files to find the appropriate hook, but note that some API requests are run through a helper function in the root commerce_paypal.module.