# Commerce- How can I modify order details with hook_commerce_paypal_wps_order_form_data_alter()?

Tags: commerce, payment-gateways

I want to modify the information Commerce sends to PayPal so that the order description on PayPal describes the product, not the order (users on my site can only order one of two products, so I think that is more useful).

This is what I want to change:
[image: This is what I want to change]

These strings are in the Commerce Website Payments Standard submodule. I am using the `hook_commerce_paypal_wps_order_form_data_alter()` function as suggested in the answer to [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/80554/commerce-paypal-how-can-i-change-the-order-no-at-site-name-string).

However, in the API, there is no example for this function (I also looked at the [Commerce Examples](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_examples) module but didn't find anything), and I'm a bit lost about how to handle it.

The string I want to override is defined in `commerce_paypal_wps_order_form()` in this section:

```
    // Define a single item in the cart representing the whole order
    'amount_1' => commerce_paypal_price_amount(commerce_currency_convert($amount, $order_currency_code, $currency_code), $currency_code),
    'item_name_1' => t('Order @order_number at @store', array('@order_number' => $order->order_number, '@store' => variable_get('site_name', url('<front>', array('absolute' => TRUE))))),
    'on0_1' => t('Product count'),
    'os0_1' => commerce_line_items_quantity($wrapper->commerce_line_items, commerce_product_line_item_types()),
  );
```

I want to change `item_name_1` to `t('My string')` and remove `on0_1` and `os0_1`.

I tried this:

```
function MYMODULE_commerce_paypal_wps_order_form_data_alter(&$data, $order) {
  $data['item_name_1'] = t('My string');
  unset($data['on0_1']);
  unset($data['os0_1']);
}
```

But nothing is changed, even after clearing the caches.  I'm having a really hard time debugging this because it is called immediately before the redirect to PayPal, so even if I use `dpm()` I'm not able to see it.

Comment: use [dd()](https://api.drupal.org/api/devel/devel.module/function/dd/7) instead of dpm.

Comment: @loolooyyyy Thanks, actually my error turned out to result from failing to clear the caches.  (Two versions of Drush, and it was reading from the wrong .drushrc.  D'oh!)  Since your answer is a good general tip, feel free to add and I will accept.

Comment: I'll add this as an answer. Thanks, that's kind of you but I don't think it's worth 100 points :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you can not see the HTML output of debugging tools such as [dpm()](https://api.drupal.org/api/devel/devel.module/function/dd/7), you should use the utility function [dd()](https://api.drupal.org/api/devel/devel.module/function/dd/7) instead. The logging data will be stored in a file called drupal_debug.txt which you can inspect later.